# flexible distance between divs

Tags: css, html

i am trying to make a list of divs of same size. I need to do it like this. I allign the divs with float left and let's say 5 divs have space in 1 line, the 6th div will go under it. Now what i need to do is the extra space that remains from this 5 divs on the line, should be divided equally between this 5 divs.

Let's say each div has 200px and the screen has 1100px width. The 5 divs now will have to have  25px between them. 200px + 25px + 200px + 25px + 200px + 25px + 200px + 25px + 200px.

Thank you in advance, Daniel.

Comment: Use jQuery, it's really all I can say, theres not much else you could do other that looking at this: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem

Comment: If your requirements allow you to specify modern version browsers, you might be able to use the CSS3 FlexBox feature: http://www.inserthtml.com/2012/05/css3-flex-box-specification-change-layout-design/

Answer (score 0):

You can float left an empty div with the width of 25px in your example or you use a percentage 25px for 1100 would be 2%

Answer (score 0):

What I tried is % widths for your divs, and % widths for the margin.  Since you want 5 divs per line the most you could do without space between or border is 20%.  In the jsfiddle below, I used 17% width and 2% on the margin-left setting.  You can customize a first div style to not pad left if need be.

```
.cell {
    height:30%;
    width:17%;
    background:#ff0000;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-bottom:2em;
    float:left;
    margin-left:2%;
}

http://jsfiddle.net/aKn4n/
```

You pretty much keep 5 divs on the first row as you shrink and grow the browser window.

Answer (score -1):

I would personally try giving each div a margin like this:

```
div{
    margin: 0px 12.5px;
}
```

This will hopefully evenly space all the divs.

Comment: The `1100px` screen width the OP gave was just an example. The spacing should be derived from the actual screen width available.

Comment: you can not divide pixel!! && 0 (zero) does not need a unit (0 buckets of water is the same as 0 K gold)

Comment: I see your point that the OP was only using an example if you needed a css to fit all purposes, but i misread it and solved just for the example. As for not being able to divide pixels you can still use .5px and it would automatically assign 13px to one side and 12px to the other, therefore adding up to a 25px gap.